# How can I convert GPS coordinate to pixel on the screen in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.1, artoolkit

I'm writing an application in c++ which gets the camera pose using fiducial markers and also as input get a lat/lon coordinate in the real world and as output streams a video with X marker which shows the location of the coordinate on the screen.

When I move my head , the X stays in the same place spatially (because I know how to move it on the screen based on the camera pose or even hide it when I look away.

My only problem is to convert the coordinate from real life to coordinate on the screen.

I know my own gps coordinate and the target gps coordinate.
I also have the screen size (height / width) .

How can I in openCV translate all these to x,y pixel on the screen ?

Comment: Could you post some sample images?

Comment: I don't have sample image , If my camera face to the north and I want to put a marker on lat/lon coordinate , my question is how I translate it from real life coordinate to pixel on the screen.

Comment: I am still unable to understand your question. Could you at least post a picture of your setup?

Comment: OpenCV has no functionality which works on GPS coordinates. You should use some other library which converts your GPS coordinates into a ground reference frames like [ENU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axes_conventions) and then use OpenCV functions inside that frame.

Answer (score 0):

In my point, your question isn't so clear.

> The opencv is an image processing library

You can't convert your needs with opencv. You've need a solution with your own algorithms. So I have some advices and some experiments to explain somethings.

You can simulate to show your real life position on screen with any programming language. Imagine it, you want to develop a measurement software, it can measure a house plan image on screen with drawing lines to edges of all walls (You know some length of walls owing to an image like below)

[image]
If you want to measure wall of WC at bottom, you must know how much pixels are how ft, so firstly you should draw a line from start to end of known length for how much pixel width it. For example, If 12'4"" ft equals 9 pixels width. no longer, you can calculate length wall of WC at bottom with use basic proportion. Of course this is basic ratio for you.

I know this is not your need but this answer is helpful for you, I hope it will give some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort , but this is not what I'm looking for.
I'll try to explain myself better and prepare example.
There is a will to help here and I have difficulties explaining what I need.
thank you.